# Could a large log file be the reason cron job keeps dying?

Tags: logs, mongodb

The log is 15 Gigabytes. I guess I have to back it up and delete. I have enough hard disc space, but did not realize log was so large. And overnight cron jobs suddenly started to die in the middle.

Comment: What exactly are these cron jobs doing?

Comment: actually they are compute-heavy, looking at every entry of every user, constantly accessing the database. The "cursor not found" error from MongoDB that I am getting is typically an indication that the cursor (query) timed out (after 10 minutes of inactivity).

Comment: @Tyra Could you provide a bit more detail about this cron job? Additionally, what is the log that you're analyzing? `logrotate` may help you get the logs to a manageable size.

Comment: My schedule.rb file is setting the output as "set :cron_log, "/opt/webapps/xxx/cron_log.log" Logrotate sounds useful. For now I just deleted the log and am running the job again. So far so good, but a log is 500 MB long in just an hour!

Comment: This cron job is accessing the database, getting a few entries according to criteria, computing something with the values, getting another set of entries, computing, until all thousands of entries are processed. It dies right before the computing part, every time in different places. Seemed to work on my laptop.

Comment: @Tyra So where does the log processing come into play? Is the log being computed/compared with something in the database? Or is the log the result of this processing

Comment: the log is the result of the processing, it just reports about every step that is done. Actually even steps that I don't want to be reported about but something happened to mongodb last time I was upgrading packages and now it outputs every little thing it does. I don't know how to turn it off. When I run jobs from the terminal, I always see long lists of queries

Comment: `logrotate` is definitely what you need to implement, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about the MongoDB log file becoming too large you should take a look at the log rotation options here:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Logging#Logging-Rotatingthelogfiles

Short version - you can rotate the logs via an admin command within MongoDB or you can send a SIGUSR1 - combine with your favorite log management method and you should be good.

Something else to consider though is why the log is so large - unless it has been running for a long, long time, 15GB is a lot of logging.  You may want to make sure that you are not starting up with logging set too high (-vv etc.).  You can also check the log level with the setParameter command.  For example, to set to 0 (the default), without restarting, just issue it like this:

```
db.adminCommand({setParameter:1, logLevel:0})
```